# How can I open files inside a subfolder in my asset folder

Tags: java, android

Hello community I'm a new developer and I'm working on an app that presents some documents to the user then the user can open them and modify their content if they wish to do so, the issue that I'm facing is these documents are numerous and they are organized in folders, what is the best way for me to proceed ? where to store these documents inside my app (can I put them in the asset folder )? how can I keep the same structure of files in my App (same organization in their respective folders)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by this way.

```
getResources().getAssets().open("subFolder/file");
```